# Correct way to set exec-path?

Tags: exec-path

The GNU elisp documentation states:

"Generally, you should not modify `exec-path` directly. Instead, ensure that your `PATH` environment variable is set appropriately before starting Emacs. Trying to modify `exec-path` independently of `PATH` can lead to confusing results."

Given that it is not, in general, possible to ensure the path is correctly set before launching emacs (macOS GUI v's terminal being my case of interest), is it possible to modify the `PATH` variable from my `.emacs`, and then have Emacs regerenate the `exec-path` variable as is done during start-up?

Edited after comment from @lawlist

Using the `exec-path-from-shell` I observe the following behaviour:

When starting Emacs:

`$PATH` = `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

`exec-path` = `"/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec" "/Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"`

After running `exec-path-from-shell-initialize`:

`$PATH` = `"/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin"`

`exec-path` = `"/opt/local/bin/" "/opt/local/sbin/" "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/" "/usr/local/bin/" "/usr/bin/" "/bin/" "/usr/sbin/" "/sbin/" "/Library/TeX/texbin/" "/opt/X11/bin/" "/Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec/"`

So the `"/Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"` component that is added to `exec-path` during Emacs start-up is removed by the `exec-path-from-shell` package. Is this expected? What is the rational for the package removing it from `exec-path`?

Comment: See:  https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Comment: You can modify any env var from Emacs, using command `setenv`.

Comment: Thank you @Drew, I have a small .el file I'm using to build the PATH vairable using setenv, it is getting it from $PATH to exec-path I'm confused by.

Comment: @lawlist, Hi, I've been playing with the exec-path-from-shell package, but I do not understand it's behaviour. I have edited my question to list the bits I don't understand in it's behaviour.

Comment: I cannot speak for Steve Purcell, but if you would like help modifying the behavior of the library, then you can either ask a question here regarding how to do that, and/or you can ask Mr. Purcell to address that issue by opening an "Issue" on Github.  To make it relevant, you might add something to the effect of wanting to use some of the executables in the `bin` directory from within Emacs.

Comment: @lawlist, Thank you for your follow-up, I'm going to raise an issue on GitHub for the behaviour of the package, to see if it's a bug, or by design.

However, the first part of the question still stands, at some point during Emacs start-up $PATH (and possibly other things) are used to construct the initial exec-path, is it possible to set $PATH (via setenv), and rerun the interesting components of Emacs start-up to obtain a new exec-path?